# Mostrar valor del ultimo dato en grafico de linea chartJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

los saludo nuevamente, les comento que estoy realizando un grafico con chartjs.
Tengo el siguiente resultado:
[image: grafico]

El problema surge que necesito poner el valor final de la linea o un texto personalizado.
Logre realizarlo de cierta manera en CODEPEN:
https://codepen.io/Maikel-Yordan/pen/dywGavq pero no he podido juntarlo con mi codigo.

El codigo es el siguiente (hay un poco de PHP ya que el grafico es dinamico segun 2 valores y se repite en varias secciones, ademas esta realiazdo con canvas ya que se exporta a PDF por wkhtml y no me funciona de otra manera):

```
'use strict';
(function(setLineDash) {
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setLineDash = function() {
        if(!arguments[0].length){
            arguments[0] = [1,0];
        }
        // Now, call the original method
        return setLineDash.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setLineDash);
Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function (thisp) {
    var fn = this;
    return function () {
        return fn.apply(thisp, arguments);
    };
};
function drawGraphs<?php echo $cont_graphic; ?>() {
    new Chart(
        document.getElementById("canvas<?php echo $cont_graphic; ?>"), {
            "type":"line",
            "data":{
                "labels":["<?php echo $f_i_e[0]; ?>","<?php echo $f_f_e[0]; ?>"],
                "datasets":[{
                    "label":"RETORNO ESPERADO EN %",
                    "data":[0, <?php echo $roe; ?>],
                    "fill":false,
                    "format": "{value}%",
                    "borderColor":"rgb(0, 192, 239)",
                    "backgroundColor": '#2196f3',
                    "borderWidth": 2,
                    "borderDash":[15, 10]
                }]
            },
            "options":{  
                tooltips: {
                   enabled: false
               },
      responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
             min: 0,
             max: <?php echo round($roe + 10, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); ?>,
             callback: function(value){return value+ "%"}
         },  
         scaleLabel: {
             display: true,
         }
         
     }]
        
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 60,
          top: 20,
          bottom: 0
      }
  }
  
}
}
);
};
window.onload = function() {
    drawGraphs<?php echo $cont_graphic; ?>();
};
drawGraphs<?php echo $cont_graphic; ?>();
```

DEBERIA QUEDAR ALGO ASI (como el de codepen):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo harian ustedes en base al codigo que deje aca? no he podido juntar el de codepen con el mio y desconozco si hay otra manera de hacerlo.